# How to use my Set/Get methods unto my main class?

Tags: java, methods, getter-setter

I am having a hard time figuring out what to do with it. For example, I have this on another class:

```
public class Methods {

    private String EmployeeName;
    private int SalaryDeduction;
    private int IDCard;

    public void setEmpName(String name) {
        this.EmployeeName = name;
    }

    public String getEmpName() {
        return EmployeeName;
    }

    public void setSalaryDed(int sdvalue) {
        this.SalaryDeduction = sdvalue;
    }

    public int getSalaryDed() {
        return SalaryDeduction;
    }

    public void setIDCard(int idcard) {
        this.IDCard = idcard;
    }

    public int getIDCard() {
        return IDCard;
    }

}
```

I need to use the above methods unto my next class. For example, the `SetEmpName` method to acquire the contents of my `EmployeeName` `JTextField` and then return it via `GetEmpName` with a button click to display it below the textfield. It will look like:

Employee Info: James

***Button Click***

Employee Info: James

"Hello James"

**EDIT**

I already know how my Set methods work, thanks man. So far, I am in dire need of knowledge on how to get my Get methods working with a click of a button. This is my program so far.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener  
 {

   //UI Components Declaration


   JLabel EmpInfL = new JLabel("Employee Info:");
   JLabel SalDedL = new JLabel("Salary Deduction:");
   JLabel IDCL = new JLabel("ID Card");

   JTextField EmpInfTF = new JTextField(8);
   JTextField SalDedTF = new JTextField(9);
   JTextField IDCTF = new JTextField(8);

   JButton OkB = new JButton();
   JButton ClearB = new JButton();

   String EmployeeName
   int SalaryDeduction;
   int IDCard;

   //Constructor
   public MainFrame() {

   super("Programming Activity");
   setSize(300,100);
   setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   setVisible(true);
   setLayout(new FlowLayout());

   add(EmpInfL);
   add(EmpInfTF);


   add(SalDedL);
   add(SalDedTF);


   add(IDCL);
   add(IDCTF);


   OkB.addActionListener(this);
   }

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
   {
   Methods SetGet = new Methods();

   SetGet.setEmpName(EmpInfTF.getText());


   }


      public static void main(String [] args)
         {

        new MainFrame();
         }
}
```

Comment: Please respect naming conventions. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367

Comment: @ZouZou This actually seems to match C# naming convention. But yeah, even part of Java's compilation is based on following the JCC linked above so it is a **really** good idea to follow it from the get-go.

Comment: @Esko: No, it doesn't. Methods in C# are PascalCased, and variables are typically camelCased.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see you're trying to use `Swing`. If you are using something like `actionListener`s, then, you can get the string from `JTextField.getText()` and store it into `setEmpName`:

something like this:

`Methods yourObject = new Methods();`
`yourObject.setEmpName(EmployeeName.getText())` in your actionListener method.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener  
 {

   //UI Components Declaration


   JLabel EmpInfL = new JLabel("Employee Info:");
   JLabel SalDedL = new JLabel("Salary Deduction:");
   JLabel IDCL = new JLabel("ID Card");
   JLabel sayHelloLabel = new JLabel("");
   JTextField EmpInfTF = new JTextField(8);
   JTextField SalDedTF = new JTextField(9);
   JTextField IDCTF = new JTextField(8);

   JButton OkB = new JButton();
   JButton ClearB = new JButton();

   String EmployeeName
   int SalaryDeduction;
   int IDCard;

   //Constructor
   public MainFrame() {

   super("Programming Activity");
   setSize(300,100);
   setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   setVisible(true);
   setLayout(new FlowLayout());

   add(EmpInfL);
   add(EmpInfTF);


   add(SalDedL);
   add(SalDedTF);


   add(IDCL);
   add(IDCTF);
   add(sayHelloLabel);

   OkB.addActionListener(this);
   }

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
   {
   Methods SetGet = new Methods();

   SetGet.setEmpName(EmpInfTF.getText());
   sayHelloLabel.setText("Hello, "+SetGet.getEmpName());

   }


      public static void main(String [] args)
         {

        new MainFrame();
         }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Aniket. But another problem has popped out. I can't seem to use the methods in my other class because it says "Cannot Find Symbol". What do I do?

Comment: @JamesTorio which "Symbol" can it not find?

Comment: The .getText() part. :/

Comment: @JamesTorio is `EmployeeName` an object of type `JTextField`?

Comment: Oh my bad. So far it has worked.

SetGet.setEmpName(EmpInfTF.getText());

How to use my getEmpName though? Final Question.

Comment: Well, then you do this: `String name = SetGet.getEmpName()` and set that to a label on your JFrame @JamesTorio

Comment: I'm a little bit lost man... Could you, perhaps, expand that a little more? >.< I'm really new on this.

Comment: @JamesTorio well show the whole code, and I will tell you how to go about it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the replies and the advices. I have edited my code. You can check it now. :)

Comment: @JamesTorio well now, see the code I have added. I hope it will show the "Hello James" in the form

Comment: My problem is solved. Thank you very much! This is truly appreciated. +1 to you:) good day sir.